# how to store and search mp3 by its content in android

Tags: android, web-services, audio

In my app i have to store a no of audio files in database in webserver and then after recording the audio in android mobile i have to send it to server to match with the previous audio files.

How to do this??

Answer (score 0):

This involves a very high understanding of audio data parsing and fingerprinting.

If you are trying to make a clone of shazam, you should read up this post :

http://laplacian.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/how-shazam-works/

Bonus : the article contains a link to an article by the very developper of Shazam.

Good luck on your endeavour.

Comment: ya i read . but I am not getting how to make fingerprints of audio ? Is there any API available for creating fingerprints?